# How to use a custom hook for showing a loader in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I tried to create a custom hook for showing the loader in react native. But the states are not getting updated in the loader component.

This is how i tried to implement the custom hook. But the **isHoverLoaderVisible** in the **HoverLoading.js** is not getting updated when I call the **showHoverloader()** in  **useLoader.js**

useLoader.js

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function useLoader() {
  const [isHoverLoaderVisible, setIsHoverLoaderVisible] = useState(false);
  const showHoverloader = value => {
    setIsHoverLoaderVisible(value);
  };

  return {isHoverLoaderVisible, showHoverloader};
}

export default useLoader;
```

HoverLoading.js

```
import {Fragment, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {ActivityIndicator, Portal, useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
import useLoader from '../../../hooks/appManagement/useLoader';

function HoverLoading() {
  const {isHoverLoaderVisible} = useLoader();
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isHoverLoaderVisible && (
        <Portal>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignContent: 'center',
              backgroundColor: theme.colors.surface + '55',
            }}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={isHoverLoaderVisible} />
          </View>
        </Portal>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default HoverLoading;
```

Comment: Well, seeing as how `showHoverloader` is never destructured from the `useLoader` hook value and called to update the `isHoverLoaderVisible` state to be anything *other than* the initially `false` value this makes complete sense that you only ever see the false value.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you should use the useLoader hook in HoverLoading.js only once and pass down the showHoverloader function as a prop to trigger state updates from useLoader.js. Here's how you can modify your code:

##### useLoader.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function useLoader() {
  const [isHoverLoaderVisible, setIsHoverLoaderVisible] = useState(false);
  const showHoverloader = (value) => {
    setIsHoverLoaderVisible(value);
  };

  return { isHoverLoaderVisible, showHoverloader };
}

export default useLoader;
```

#### HoverLoading.js

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { ActivityIndicator, Portal, useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import useLoader from '../../../hooks/appManagement/useLoader';

function HoverLoading() {
  // use showHoverloader here to set the state of the loader
  // OR
  // keep useLoader() in the parent component
  // and pass isHoverLoaderVisible as a prop to this component
  const { isHoverLoaderVisible, showHoverloader } = useLoader();
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Portal>
        {isHoverLoaderVisible && (
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignContent: 'center',
              backgroundColor: theme.colors.surface + '55',
            }}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={isHoverLoaderVisible} />
          </View>
        )}
      </Portal>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default HoverLoading;
```